# What format choice for an Ubuntu back up disk?

Tags: backup, format

[image: Screenshot of format choices]I would like to use a 1Tb external disk for my backup using the standard Ubuntu backup tool.The disk has been used previously and I need to format and wipe it. As a new user I don't know which format I should choose. I have attached a screenshot showing my choices. Can anyone advise on which I should choose please?

The volume name is currently "Acer". is it possible to change this name?

Comment: I prefer `ext4` as it's fully POSIX compliant, and I usually find keeping it simple is best (KISS).  It'll depend exactly how you're going to use the disk though & what backup programs/scripts (will all backups be tarball type), eg. if you're going to also backup other machines (esp. if say windows) then `ext4` may not be the best approach.  There are *pros* and *cons* for all file-systems.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I've no idea what a tarball is. Also, In normal use my machine will revert to a login screen if not used for a while. Will this stop an unattended backup?

Comment: @JeffreyR A tarball is the ancient Linux archive format. Think of it as a zip file. If you "pause" your system, unattended backups will run, unless your system decides to go into sleep mode. See the energy tab on the Settings panel for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll get the best performance using a Linux-native filesystem (like `ext4`). And since your usecase is backup of Ubuntu data, I'd say this is the recommended option.

And although the dialogue says "Internal disk", you can actually format any disk with `ext4`, be it an external HDD, SSD or USB drive (it's really a curious way to word this option).

However, you may have specific needs (that we don't know) where you would need portability in which case FAT or NTFS is an option. But in this case you'll probably loose some Linux-native filesystem metadata (in particular permissions and symbolic links).

Comment: To add to this answer: The most important metadata that you will lose is a) file permissions and b) symbolic links. If you need to backup plain documents and media, that is not a problem. If you need to backup (and restore) a folder of Linux executables and associated files, that may be a concern.

Comment: Thank you for this help. The option ext4 is presented as specific to internal disks whereas mine is external in a caddy. I presume this is still ok?

Comment: @JeffreyR I elaborated on this.